# ErrorException : Undefined variable: days

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**UsermailRespoitory**

I want the days should be added inside addDays()
The days i will get frm my database

```
public function create() 
    {

        $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
        $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all()->pluck('days');


        foreach ($users as $user) {

           if( $user->created_at > Carbon::now()->addDays($days)){
                if ($user->created_at < Carbon::now()) //signup
                {    
                    return false;
                }
                    Mail::to($user)->send(new Automail($template));
                    return true;

           }
}
```

Comment: `if( $user->created_at > Carbon::now()->addDays($days)){`there is no days variable

Comment: > "I want the days should be added inside addDays() The days i will get frm my database"
So do this... `$days= //however you get days from your database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function create() 
    {

        $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
        $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all();


        foreach ($users as $user) {
            foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail){

                if( $user->created_at > Carbon::now()->addDays($mail->days)){
                        if ($user->created_at < Carbon::now()) //signup
                        {    
                            return false;
                        }
                            Mail::to($user)->send(new Automail($template));
                            return true;

                }
```